# UITextField > force cursor to stay at the end of the field

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, cursor, uitextfield

The user should not be able to move the cursor of a UITextField somwhere else in the entered string.

I need this because I want the user to enter a currency amount. This is done by letting the user enter numbers which will be added to the end of the amount and the commata will be moved to the third position from the end.

How do I force the cursor in an UITextField to stay at the end of an entered string?

Comment: So if I enter “1,799,999.95” when I meant “1,599,999.95”, I'll have to delete nearly the entire string and retype it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by hiding the original entry field and show the value formatted in a label. This prevents the user from changing the cursors position.

Answer (score 2):

Place a `UIButton` over your `UITextField`. Add an `IBAction` to the button and have it call `UITextField.becomeFirstResponder()`.

This prevents clicks from passing, cursors for being able to be modified, but still allows the user to click the view and select it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of UITextField with

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { return NO; }
```

to disable all gestures on that field. This implies that you make that field the firstResponder programmatically though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Just give him the correct range.

Comment: If I undestood the documentation correctly this would just ignore a number added somewhere in the middle. But I want to force the cursor to stay at the end of the field.

Comment: when the user write a new letter u can force textfield to print it any particular location.